# AngularJS' $sce.trustAsHtml being ignored

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to AngularJS and I feel like I'm just scratching the surface of what's possible with the framework. However, I'm running into problems with the sce.trustAsHtml function. I'm running AngularJS 1.2.4.

In my application, I'm loading items using JSON. These items are displayed in a list using a directive. Sometimes, I would want to inject HTML into the retrieved content (e.g. to make links clickable).

I've read I can use $sce.trustAsHtml to allow html in the binds. However, the following snippet isn't working. I would expect all items to be replaced with a bold text 'test', but instead it's displaying `<strong>Test</strong>` for each item.

Is there a simple way to make this snippet work?

```
angular.directive('ngStream', function($timeout, $sce) {
    var url = "getitems.json";
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'templates/app_item.html',
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
            $scope.getItems = function() {
                $http.get(url,{}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                    $scope.items = data;
                });
            }
        }],
        link: function(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {
            scope.getItems();
            scope.$watch('items', function(newVal) { if (newVal) {
                angular.forEach(newVal, function(vars,i) {
                    # Example html string for testing purposes.
                    var editedContent = '<strong>Test</strong>';
                    newVal[i].contentHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(editedContent)
                });
            }});
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's on your template? `$sce.trustAsHtml` must be used with `ng-bind-html` instead of normal `ng-bind` (or `{{}}`)

Comment: Thanks! My template used to be: `{{ item.contentHtml }}`. By changing it to `<span ng-bind-html="item.contentHtml"></span>` it worked. Do you know of an even cleaner way to use ng-bind-html (not using an unnecessary span tag)?

Comment: AFAIK this is the only way to use `ng-bind-html`.

Comment: You saved my day by emphasizing on *must be used with `ng-bind-html`*