# $sce.trustAsHtml not working

Tags: angularjs

Alright, so the following below that I've tested in code works:

**javascript:**

```
var string = '<p>hello</p>';
$scope.html = $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
```

**html:**

```
<span ng-bind-html="html"></span>
```

The thing I'm really trying to do is this: Pulling a bunch of items from the server in JSON form. One of the JSON's key is called "description", which is just a long string of html code.

I'm pushing these items into a $scope array so I can show them on the page through an ng-repeat directive. The code below summarizes how it's being done:

**javascript:**

```
$.getJSON('someURL', function(data) {
    $scope.items = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.count; i++) {
        var item = {};
        item.description = $sce.trustAsHtml(data.item[i].description);
        $scope.items.push(item);
    }
});
```

**html:**

```
<p ng-repeat="item in items">
    <span ng-bind-html="item.description"></div>
</p>
```

This isn't producing any output for some reason. Something I read was that whatever variable you bind the $sce.trustAsHtml() to must be a $scope variable. In this case, I'm setting it to a regular variable "item.description" and then adding it to a $scope.item array.

I suspect this may be why it's not working, but I don't know how to go about fixing it.

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, I found an answer here on:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24459194/angularjs-using-sce-trustashtml-with-ng-repeat

Comment: Seems like this **[should be working](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/kYmr4/)**. Are you sure `data.item[i].description` has the proper data ? What is the structure of `data` ?

Comment: **1.** Make sure you upvote that very useful answer that you found ;) **2.** I don't think that approach is necessary in your case. Something else should be wrong (See my comment above).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492758/angularjs-sce-trustashtml-being-ignored

Answer (score 9):

Try `<span ng-bind-html="'{{item.description}}'"></span>`.

Something like this worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

With AngularJS 1.4.9 it worked for me like this:

Controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$sce',
    function($scope, $sce) {
        $scope.infoText = $sce.trustAsHtml('My <strong>HTML text</strong>');
    }
])
```

Template:

```
<span ng-bind-html="infoText"></span>
```