# AngularJS JSON Won't Insert <input> Tag

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I am having trouble putting a  tag into my AngularJS web app. It loads data from a JSON file just fine. It also recognizes my HTML tags such as `<em>` and `<br />`. I achieved this through the $sce trustAsHtml. But it does not work for `<input>` tags. I have tried for two days but I could not find a solution that works. Help and explanations are appreciated!

**index.html**

```
<div ng-bind-html="myName.name"></div> <!-- The Test from the data.json file shows up in italic but the input does not show up in the DOM -->
```

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngAnimate',
    'QuizController'
]);

myApp.filter('trustAsHtml', [
    '$sce',
    function($sce) {
        return function(value) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
        }
    }
]);
```

**data.json**

```
"name" : "<em>Test</em> <input type='text' name='Hello'>"
```

Comment: Let me know if this duplicate doesn't answer your question.

Comment: An exact duplicate? Can you link to the question?

Comment: This one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24461603/sce-trustashtml-not-working. You can just click on the text above.

Comment: No, I've gone through that solution and as I said in my question I call my data and strings and HTML fine, it's the input specifically that won't work. It's not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Sorry mate. I have reopened the question. Good luck with answers. `:)`

Comment: Do you mean that Test shows up in italics?  Having the name attribute of the input showing up in italics sounds like odd behavior that I can't explain.

Comment: Your right, the Test shows in italics. I have edited for clarity thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined a filter (`trustAsHtml`), which you don't apply to your value. Therefore the contents of `ng-bind-html` is not run through the filter and is not, actually, trusted.

As pointed out by georgeawg in the comments below, a number of [safe tags](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L346) are, in fact, allowed through `ng-bind-html` without the need to be run through `$sce.trustAsHtml()` and `<em>` is one of those tags.

But `<input>` is not.

Therefore, you need to apply your filter to allow unsafe tags through `ng-bind-html`, by changing the markup to:

```
<div class="txt" ng-bind-html="myName.name | trustAsHtml"></div>
```

---

<strike>It should work, though I haven't actually tested it in AngularJS environment. To do it, I'd first need to know what version you're using.</strike>

See it working here:

```js
(function(){
  // Declare App
  var app = angular.module('testApp',[]);
  
  
  app.controller('testCtrl', ['$scope','$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
    $scope.waiting = true;
    $timeout(() => {
      $scope.waiting = false;
      $scope.name = "<em>Test</em> <input type='text' name='Hello'>";
    }, 1000);
  }]).filter('trustAsHtml', [
    '$sce',
    function($sce) {
        return function(value) {
          return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
        }
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="testApp">
 <div ng-controller="testCtrl">
  <div ng-bind-html="name | trustAsHtml"></div>
  <div ng-show="waiting">let's wait a second...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The txt class is not adding the italic, it does indeed work as I am looking at the italic text and can change it to use <br> <b> and other tags. I did try the actual filter at one point but I got this error message in the console: Error
 "<div class="txt" ng-bind-html="myName.name | trustAsHtml">" angular.min.js:125

Comment: To answer your question I am using AngularJS v1.6.7

Comment: If the text is italic is not proof `<em>` passes `ng-bind-html`. The only proof it does is if you inspect the source and you see the `<em>` tag inside `<div class="txt"></div>` in the live page. Even so, I'm telling you, you're not running the contents of `myName.name` through the filter you defined. Ok, I'll try to recreate using 1.6.7. I haven't worked with 1.6 much.

Comment: I believe you, I am unsure why it works. I checked the DOM tree and I can confirm Test is wrapped in <em></em> tags

Comment: In that case `ng-bind-html` allows harmless tags in 1.6 (which is nice, but totally unexpected - therefore not used by many users coming from older versions). It didn't use to work this way up to 1.5 - any HTML had to be run through `$sce`). I'll fiddle your example and see if I run into any probs.

Comment: @user5854648, I added a basic example, using 1.6. As you can see, it works. If it doesn't in your case, your problem is elsewhere. You need to reproduce it here if you want it debugged. Since I don't have a json source, I just added the contents later, using a timeout. Do note that if you newly added HTML has anything that needs to be compiled by angular, it will only work once you run it through `$compile`.

Comment: This was really helpful. So I had the .filter in the app.js so based on your example I removed it and tacked it to the end of my MainController instead and this caused the input to work. I suppose in retrospect that makes more sense, but I had created a app before with it in the app.js but never used the <input> tag and I simply didn't know any better. Thanks for your help!

Comment: The `ng-bind-html` directive allows the `<em>` tag because it is on the while list of trusted elements. See the [source code for ngSanitize.js L346](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L346).

Comment: @george, thanks. Already figured that out. What I didn't, yet, was in what version the list was implemented.

Comment: That whitelist was in `ngSanitize.js` when it was initially committed Oct 18, 2010 with [committ 4fdab37](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/4fdab3765919e9fffc6d2f84e74754b1012997be#diff-953786501fb82b0101b7d15a1b3873cb). That means it has worked that way since V1.0.rc2

Comment: @georgeawg I remember needing `$sce.trustAsHtml()` for `<span>` elements a couple of years back, on `v1.2`. Of course, I acknowledge human memory is not, technically, a reliable source of information. :)

Answer (score 1):

From you example it's unclear how do you use `trustAsHtml` filter.

Anyway, seems like `$sce.trustAsHtml()` is getting the job done:

```js
(function(angular) {
  'use strict';
angular.module('bindHtmlExample', ['ngSanitize'])
  .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$sce', function($scope, $sce) {
    $scope.myHTML = $sce.trustAsHtml(
       "<em>Test</em> <input type='text' name='Hello'>");
  }]);
})(window.angular);

/*
Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license
*/
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-ng-bind-html-production</title>

  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  
 
</head>
<body ng-app="bindHtmlExample">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But keep in mind that you won't be able to use `ng-model` with an input rendered like that because you need to compile it first. You'll need a `$compile` service for that.

Comment: This doesn't work as I am calling the <input> tag from a JSON file and using a .filter to apply it. It is true, in my current HTML I am not calling it, for some odd reason I get a error message when I try using the filter. The error I get: Error
 "<div class="txt" ng-bind-html="myQuestion.question | trustAsHtml">" angular.min.js:125

Comment: @user5854648 okay, this might be because you didn't register `trustAsHtml` filter correctly.

Comment: This is the instance I use filter in the app: myApp.filter('trustAsHtml', [
    '$sce',
    function($sce) {
        return function(value) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(value);
        }
    }
]);